# Google App script extracting local computer name

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible that once the Google form has been submitted, we can return the local computername or username of my computer using google app script to google spreadsheet??

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the entirety of [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) is such method mentioned.